# Azure Search Fuzzy Suggest Across Multiple Fields

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Given I have my index configured as such:

```
{
  "Error": null,
  "IsSuccess": true,
  "StatusCode": 201,
  "Body": {
    "name": "test-want-index",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "Id",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": false,
        "filterable": false,
        "sortable": false,
        "facetable": false,
        "suggestions": false,
        "key": true,
        "retrievable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Title",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": true,
        "filterable": false,
        "sortable": false,
        "facetable": false,
        "suggestions": true,
        "key": false,
        "retrievable": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Description",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": true,
        "filterable": false,
        "sortable": false,
        "facetable": false,
        "suggestions": true,
        "key": false,
        "retrievable": true
      },
    ],
    "scoringProfiles": [],
    "defaultScoringProfile": null,
    "corsOptions": null
  }
}
```

populated with this data:

```
Id:123, Title:starbucks, Description:coffee that is good
Id:456, Title:big b, Description:coffee that is bad
Id:789, Title:elk brand, Description:we have elk stars
```

When a user that enters the following query `starbucs coffee`

**Is it possible to configure the index fields so that I can:**

1. match item with id 123 and id 456
2. Fuzzy search (or suggestion?) Title AND Description

Note:

1. Entering `stabuck` as the search term for suggestion returns id 123
2. Entering `coffee` as the search term for suggestion returns id 456
3. Entering `starbucs coffee` returns nothing. <- **my problem**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't currently handle spelling corrections/fuzzy queries on search. We're working on making linguistics better in general this a number of these things will improve over time.

In this particular case, search and suggestions don't return anything for different reasons:

Search comes back empty because it doesn't do fuzzy matching, thus starbucs doesn't match. Note that if searchMode is set to "any" (default), the document should still come back because "coffee" is a match.

Suggestions come back empty because it does a full match only, and there's no single field that contains the whole string "starbucks coffee" (with or without misspellings). We've gotten a ton of "passionate feedback" about the fact that suggestions is prefix-only, and we're looking at how to make this more flexible.

Sorry I don't have a very actionable answer, other than making sure you have &searchMode=any so search will match other words. The rest will get better but we need a bit of time. We push new bits with new functionality every week, so things are progressing quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It is available now as a feature in the suggestor refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798936.aspx